# PayPal API: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, api, paypal

There are a lot of posts about this error, but they all not apply on me. I really don't understand why the amounts wouldn't match. I have ITEMAMT which matches AMT0 * QTY0. And AMT matches ITEMAMT + SHIPPINGAMT. I checked the docs over and over and it really should work this way. It works when I totally remove the shipping out of it...

The AMT in the checkout url is 73.9 too.

I really hope someone is familiar with this very confusing error, and knows what I am doing wrong...

Thanks in advance

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-01-24T22:56:09Z
    [CORRELATIONID] =>
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 62.0
    [BUILD] => 4181146
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
Array
(
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => XXXX
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 30533
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => XXXX
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 30.95
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 2
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 61.9
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 12
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 73.9
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [REQCONFIRMSHIPPING] => 1
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => XXXX
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => XXXX
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => XX
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => XX
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => XXXXXX
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => XXXXXXXX
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is probably not helpful to most of you passing by. But one of my items contained an & in the description (L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0). '&' escaped the data passed through with CURL. And that created the error (which is totally off). Remember that this will also happen when you put in any characters that will contain an & when the URL is being encoded e.g. é will become `&eacute;`

I apologize for removing the item description from my first post, but i had no idea this had something to do with it, due to the error message about amounts.

Answer (score 4):

It is mandatory that you send currency with 2 decimal places. It appears that you are only providing 1.

```
$amt = 61.9;
$amt = sprintf("%.2f",$amt); // 61.90
```

Paypal will return this error because the amount is not in the correct format:

Take a look at `Table A.2` under the `AMT` row:

> http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html

This rule should apply every time you set a 'money' parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem to do the trick:
    [AMT] => 73.90
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 30.95
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 61.90
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 12.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 73.90

Still got the exact same error

Comment: @Chris did you find a solution i am having the same issue. With decimals i get errors. I am trying to split the totalprice in totalpriceexvat + vat before sending to paypal

Comment: i have turned every money var sprintf("%.2f",$var)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem few days ago when trying to communicate, then only i realized that these order totals do not really match, with some minute decimal places. If you try the communication with some whole numbers like 50, as item amt and total (without any precession) then it will not give any error. I was also breaking my head and though paypal has some problem. (but really i was)
So you better check the calculations and note that paypal will accept amounts upto only 2 precession or decimal places. I agree with Samuel on what he said.

Even the shipping amount you better send them as 12.00 instead of 12 and other numbers like 61.90, 73.90 ...

Comment: I know that that's required, just like Samuel Cook said. But that wasn't really the case here. I used round($value, 2) in php, which means it will round to two decimals, if thats required. 12.00 will be 12, 61.90 will be 61.9 and 30.95 will be 30.95. Its not that PayPal doesn't accept values with less than two decimals, but if you don't round to two decimals, the values don't add up in PayPal's calculations. If you give them AMT0 => 10.55, QTY0 => 2 paypal will calculate that to 21.10, a ITEMAMT of 21.1 will be fine, but do QTY0 => 3 and the value is 31.65, which requires you to have two dec's