# PayPal NVP: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, paypal

I am setting up reference transactions with PayPal NVP API. My issue is with adding tax amounts to a digital product. I get the error

`The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts`

Without my tax amounts, I have no errors.. This charges successfully.

```
$post = [
            'METHOD' => 'DoReferenceTransaction',
            'REFERENCEID' => $billingId,
            'PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',
            'AMT' =>  sprintf("%.2f", $plan->total),
            'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
        ];
```

Once I tried to add he `TAXAMT`, I got the aforementioned error.

```
$post = [
            'METHOD' => 'DoReferenceTransaction',
            'REFERENCEID' => $billingId,
            'PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',
            'AMT' =>  sprintf("%.2f", $plan->total),
            'TAXAMT' => sprintf("%.2f", $plan->taxAmount),
            'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
        ];
```

I've verified that `$plan->taxAmount` is a valid number (3.25).

Comment: Are you including that tax amount into the total order amount to charge?

Comment: I'm assuming you read through the docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/ ... it explains the differences between AMT, ITEMAMT, TAXAMT, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal API: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512491/paypal-api-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts)

Comment: @Randall Yes I've read the docs (how else would I be using the API?). It does not explain the differences between them, if you ask me. Clearly I am confused on how to add taxes. I also don't understand if I need to be using the NVP values that start with `L_` (I also tried with no success). This is a digital product.

Comment: why are you using NVP and not REST APIs ?